# How to add multiple markers in Google map with Flutter Web?

Tags: flutter, google-maps, flutter-web

How can I add multiple markers by tap/click the map in Google map with Flutter Web?
All of the tutorial were using [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter)  not [google_maps_flutter_web](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter_web).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
//list of markers 
final Set<Marker> markers = new Set();

markers.add(Marker( //add first marker
  markerId: MarkerId(showLocation.toString()),
  position: showLocation, //position of marker
  infoWindow: InfoWindow( //popup info 
    title: 'My Custom Title ',
    snippet: 'My Custom Subtitle',
  ),
  icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker, //Icon for Marker
));

markers.add(Marker( //add second marker
  markerId: MarkerId(showLocation.toString()),
  position: LatLng(27.7099116, 85.3132343), //position of marker
  infoWindow: InfoWindow( //popup info 
    title: 'My Custom Title ',
    snippet: 'My Custom Subtitle',
  ),
  icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker, //Icon for Marker
)); 

GoogleMap( //Map widget from google_maps_flutter package
  markers: markers, //markers to show on map
)
```

Comment: Where should I put them?